# Cleaning a Jerrycan

Tags: fuel-system, oil, cleaning, fuel-tank

I have a couple of 10 Litre steel jerrycans which I used for draining kerosene (UN1223 28sec burning oil) from a tank. After disposing of the kerosene I left the open jerrycans upside down over some oil-absorbing pellets for a couple of days.

I would like to re-use these jerrycans to store unleaded petrol (gasoline) for my car - which is what they are designed for. Do they need further cleaning or is the tiny amount of kerosene residue unlikely to do any harm.

Comment: http://www.smokstak.com/library/technical-information-7/running-kerosene-in-a-gasoline-engine-23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small amount of residue left will do no harm.

Comment: To add to Mike's answer, kerosene is a petroleum distillate, similar enough to gasoline that a small amount of kerosene mixed in with the gasoline will have no noticeable effect.  Some gasoline engines can even be [modified to use kerosene](http://www.smokstak.com/library/technical-information-7/running-kerosene-in-a-gasoline-engine-23/).